# Google search : How do I search for Laravel functions and its documentation?

Tags: search, laravel

For example, when I want to search for Laravel's `get()` function I would type

```
Laravel "get()" function
```

but it gives me

```
.... Get the fully ....
....getting started ...
```

on the first page of the search results. How do I reduce the scope to find the exact get() function on the first page? JQuery functions doesn't seem to experience this problem when I type its functions in the google search bar. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, check out sourcegraph.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Google's `site:` operator ([See docs here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en)):

```
site:laravel.com get()
```

[Search link here](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3alaravel.com%20get%28%29&safe=active)